# How to make the navbar menu for mobile devices occupy 100% of the screen of my device

Tags: javascript, css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I hope you can help me, I am doing a landing page that is very responsive, and adapts perfectly to mobile devices. I want to make the navigation menu cover the entire screen in the case of mobile devices.
but I could not achieve it.
I want that when the page is seen in mobile devices and the toggle button is clicked, the options menu appears to cover the whole screen, something like this:

[image]

In the image above, that menu when it is displayed covers the entire screen, both in width and height.

On my webpage that does not happen, when I click on the toggle button to display the menu, it's like this:

[image]

As you can see, the menu only covers half of the screen, and I want that although it has few options, it still covers all the size of the screen.
How could I achieve this? With CSS and maybe also JavaScript.

This is my HTML code:

```
          <body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar-collapse" data-offset="50">

    <!-- navigation section -->
       <section class="navbar navbar-fixed-top custom-navbar bg-trans" role="navigation" id="navbar_menu">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
         <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="icon icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="nav-brand" href="index.php"><img src="images/nivaLogo.png" alt="logo" title="Nivamedia" id="main_logo"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" id="list_options">
            <li><a href="index.php" class="smoothScroll itemLi">HOME</a></li>
             <li class="dropdown">
              <a class="dropdown-toggle itemLi" data-toggle="dropdown">LEISTUNGEN</a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="dropdown-main" style="background-color: white; color: black;">
                                    <li><a href="webdesign.php" class="itemUlLi">Webdesign & Entwicklung</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="corporate-design.php" class="itemUlLi">Corporate Design</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="online-marketing.php" class="itemUlLi">Online Marketing</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="lieferdienst.php" class="itemUlLi">Lieferdienst Webshop</a></li>
                                </ul>
                </li>
            <li><a href="projekte.php" class="smoothScroll itemLi">PROJEKTE</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about" class="smoothScroll itemLi">AGENTUR</a></li>
            <li><a href="kontakt.php" class="smoothScroll itemLi">KONTAKT</a></li>
        </ul>
       </div>
      </div>
      </section>
       </body>
```

This is my CSS media Queries

```
              @media (max-width: 767px) and (min-width: 320px) 
        {

         .just_text
        {
            margin-left: 2px !important;
            margin-right: 20px !important;
        }

        .title_left
        {
            text-align: center !important;
        }

        #main_logo
        {
          padding-top: 0px !important;
          padding-bottom: 0px !important;
          padding-left: 25px !important;
        }

        #navbar_menu 
        {
            border-bottom: 0;
            background: transparent; /*0 0*/;
        }

        /* #navbar_container 
        {
            width: -webkit-fill-available !important;
            height: -webkit-fill-available !important;
        }
        */
        #dropdown-main 
        {
        background-color: white !important;
        background: white !important;
        padding-right: 0px !important;

        }

        .itemUlLi
        {

        color: black !important;
        font-size: 18px !important;

        }

        #list_options
        {
            margin-top: 0px !important;
            padding-top: 0px !important;
            padding-bottom: 20px !important;
        }

        .itemLi
        {
            font-size: 20px !important;
        }

        .list_options_Li
        {
        padding-bottom: 30px !important;
        }

        .dropdown_li
        {
            padding-top: 15px !important;
        }

        #list_options 
        {
            padding-top: 0px !important;
            padding-bottom: 0px !important;
            margin-bottom: 0px !important;
        }

        #services_title div.section-title
        {
            padding-right: 11px !important;
            padding-left: 11px !important;
        }


        #icon_mobile
         {
         display: inline-block !important;
         }

        #dropdown-main
        {
            padding-right: 0px !important;
            margin-right: 0px !important;
            padding-top: 15px !important;
            width: 100% !important;
            padding-left: 30px !important;
        }

        .navbar-toggle
        {
            margin-top: 20px !important;
            margin-right: 25px !important;
        }

        .collapse.in
        {
            background-color: white !important;
            position: relative !important;
            top: 0 !important; 
            padding-left: 20px !important;
        }

        .collapse.in ul
        {
            background-color: white !important;
        }

        .collapse.in ul li a
        {
            color: black !important;
        }

        .off
        {
        display: none !important;
        }
         .display_line
          {
            display: block !important;
            color: blue !important;
            font-weight: bold !important;
            width: 20% !important;
            margin-left: 16px !important;
            margin-right: 0px !important;
            margin-top: 0% !important;
            margin-bottom: 0% !important;
            border-top: 2px solid blue !important;
            text-align: left !important; 
          }

          #menu_collapse 
          { height: 100vh !important; }


        } /* end of media queries */
```

I'm using bootstrap for design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `height: 100vh` didn't work for you, you might be able to get it with
`min-height: 100vh`

Comment: No problem, happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `height: 100vh` in the CSS to use up 100% of the viewport height. Another alternative is to use `position: fixed; top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0;` to cover the whole screen.

Comment: You mean `100vh`, I'm pretty sure `vh100` is a syntax error.

Comment: nothing, it can't work for me, the menu's still the same.

Comment: @RolandF: which element are you applying the styles to? Check to make sure the computed styles don't show something else overwriting your sizing styles.

Comment: @Jacob in div with class= navbar-collapse

Comment: what I have noticed is that the menu also has a scroll effect, then if I click on the LEISTUNGEN option, a dropdown should be opened with other options, but the menu does not expand but remains in the middle, the scroll is automatically activated

Answer (score 0):

Another option: `fill-available`

```css
height: -moz-available;
height: -webkit-fill-available;
height: fill-available;
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `height: 100vh;` to your styles like this:

```
.navbar-collapse {
    height: 100vh;
}
```